# find rows in document term matrix for which row totals are 0 in R

Tags: r, text-mining, topic-modeling

I am trying to perform topic modeling on chat data in R.
I am good till the process of creating of Document term matrix.

```
dtm<- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
dtm<-removeSparseTerms(dtm, sparse=0.995)
library(topicmodels)
rowTotals <- apply(dtm, 1, sum)
dtm2 <- dtm[rowTotals>0,]
ldaGibbs5 <- LDA(dtm,5)

gammaDF <- as.data.frame(ldaGibbs5@gamma) 
names(gammaDF) <- terms(ldaGibbs5)
gammaDF

topics<-colnames(gammaDF)[max.col(gammaDF, ties.method = 'first')]
```

Till here I found the topic to which each document belongs to. i am now trying to map these topics to the original data frame.

```
Chat2way$topic<-topics
```

The following is the error

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "topic", value = c("customer", "email",  : 
  replacement has 1530 rows, data has 3561
```

This is because i removed some rows of dtm for which row totals are 0.
I would like to know which rows i removed in dtm so that i could remove the same rows in my original data frame also.

Thanking in anticipatory

Comment: Try `which(slam::row_sums(dtm) == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

The following code will show the document IDs of empty rows.

```
rowTotals <- apply(dtm, 1, sum)
empty_rows <- dtm[rowTotals == 0, ]$dimnames[1][[1]]
```